# C# MongoDB Distinct Query Syntax

Tags: c#, mongodb, distinct, distinct-values

I am trying to get the distinct values from a field in MongoDB. I am having real trouble with the Syntax. Using mongoshell it's relatively easy to do, this is the query I run:

```
db.cmstest.distinct("categories")
```

This query returns an array of strings with all the distinct values.

Now I am trying to get the syntax right using the latest official MongoDB Drivers, but not to much success. This is my code, which is unsuccessful:

```
var categoriesList = await blogContext.Articles.DistinctAsync<List<string>>("categories", "");
```

Mind you categories is a `List<string>`.

Could anyone help shed some light? I've tried looking both in the documentation and online and haven't found much.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try the following approach:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument();
var categoriesList = await blogContext.Articles.DistinctAsync<string>("categories", filter);
```

Comment: I'd prefer `DistinctAsync<dynamic>` instead of `DistinctAsync<string>` as it's safer than strict typecasting. Just my two cents. otherwise, good solution.

Comment: @Saleem I concur, though solution is coming from the OP's perspective where they are expecting a distinct string list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I used this, based on what you said: `var categoriesList = await blogContext.Articles.Distinct<string>("categories", "{}").ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 2):

Better yet you can use a lambda expression to be type safe.

For example:

`await this.Collection.DistinctAsync(flow => flow.timestampDate, new BsonDocument());`