# Get distinct nested document values from a collection in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query

This question involves getting distinct values of a nested document in Mongo DB using C#. I have a collection of documents, each document having the structure:

```
{
   key1: value1,
   key2: value2,
   key3: {
      nestedKey1: nestedValue1,
      nestedKey1: nestedValue1
   }
}
```

I need to query a list of distinct **nestedKey1** values based on the value of **key1**. I can do this (using a shell in Robomongo) by using the command:

```
db.runCommand({distinct:'collection_name', key:'key3.nestedKey1', query: {key1: 'some_value'}})
```

But how do I achieve this in C# ([tutorial here](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/client/))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# MongoDB Distinct Query Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725113/c-sharp-mongodb-distinct-query-syntax)

Comment: @Veeram How do I specify the key key3.nestedKey1 in this case? and not to forget the filter which has to be key1: 'some_value'

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below distinct query.

```
IMongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
IMongoDatabase db = mongo.GetDatabase("databasename");
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collectionname");

BsonDocument filter = new BsonDocument("key1", "some_value");
IList<BsonDocument> distinct = collection.Distinct<BsonDocument>("key3.nestedKey1", filter).ToList<BsonDocument>();
```

Filter Builder Variant

```
var builder = Builders<YourClass>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(item => item.key1, "some_value");
IList<string> distinct = collection.Distinct<string>("key3.nestedKey1", filter).ToList<string>();
```

Field Builder Variant

```
var builder = Builders<YourClass>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(item => item.key1, "some_value");
FieldDefinition<YourClass, string> field = "key3.nestedKey1";
IList<string> distinct = collection.Distinct<string>(field", filter).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: I found the solution. And it is very similar to your answer. Thanks