# delete multiple array from collection in mongodb in asp.net core

Tags: json, mongodb, asp.net-core

Below is my json string in MongoDB i want to delete MasterColors Array on MasterColorGuid in Asp.net Core

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595657a00c1ac702f6e4f5cb"),
    "IsActive" : true,
    "IPAddress" : null,
    "CreatedBy" : "46F5C2E8-83F4-4062-8CD7-1B567B303919",
    "CreatedDateUtc" : ISODate("2017-06-30T13:51:38.324Z"),
    "ModifiedBy" : "46F5C2E8-83F4-4062-8CD7-1B567B303919",
    "ModifiedDateUtc" : ISODate("2017-06-30T13:51:38.324Z"),
    "WebSiteGuid" : "12E36FB8-D1B5-4172-8144-1176C0AFA82D",
    "ProductGuid" : "8D647BE5-8ABC-4AD8-8342-1254C8096DC8",
    "ProductName" : "Built® Netbook & Laptop Sleeve 9-10\"",
    "ProductCode" : "BT-5603",
    "MasterColors" : [ 
        {
            "MasterColorGuid" : "49e35057-39a6-4772-93c9-fc10aa87eff8",
            "SkuGuid" : "C634041D-116E-447A-A806-9CA04E4DA5B4"
        }, 
        {
            "MasterColorGuid" : "8ae4d05e-96f4-486d-9a2f-b1535f711f9f",
            "SkuGuid" : "04A03C81-07BC-4609-9311-C051784B1502"
        }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you share .NET code you've written so far to delete the array?

Comment: the question is wrong i want to make a query to extract data from mongodb in asp.net core the query in mongodb is :db.getCollection('Products').distinct("ProductSKUs.VariantName" , {"WebSiteGuid":"12E36FB8-D1B5-4172-8144-1176C0AFA82D"}) in short i want to get all distincint varaint name of all products how will i pass this query in asp.net core. @Ignas

Comment: You should fix your question. See if this helps.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850951/get-distinct-nested-document-values-from-a-collection-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp/44885033#44885033

Comment: Can we update the solution using Builders and Filterdefination of MongoDB driver @Veeram

Comment: I just did, but please update your question or you can just delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var collection = _Productcontext.GetCollection(Collection);
                var distinct = collection
                              .Distinct(new StringFieldDefinition("ProductSKUs.VariantName"), filterSelect)
                              .ToList();
                return distinct;