# MongoDB C# - Make list of different items

Tags: c#, mongodb

Let's assume I have a class like this:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and I have a collection of *MyObject* in MongoDB.

How can I go through the collection and make a list of all the unique colors?

At the end, I'd like a List that contains one entry per color { "yellow", "pink" } for example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the distinct values from the `color` field (assuming you use the standard serialization names).  See [C# MongoDB Distinct Query Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725113/c-sharp-mongodb-distinct-query-syntax) for examples of how to do that.

I believe this should work, but have not tested it, assuming that `collection` is your collection object:
`var colors = await collection.DistinctAsync<List<string>>("color", "{}").ToListAsync();`

Comment: I had never seen the "distinct" method; thanks! let me look into that and I'll report back.